# Python: multiple packages with multiple setup.py files

Tags: python, package, setup.py, namespace-package

I'm having a hard time constructing my Python setup.py files to do what I want. I have one pacakge set up like this:

```
somestuff_root/
    setup.py
    myutils/
        __init__.py
        a/
            __init__.py
            somestuff.py
```

I have another package setup like this:

```
otherstuff_root/
    setup.py
    myutils/
        __init__.py
        b/
            __init__.py
            otherstuff.py
```

so things are organized in my site-packages/ directory like:

```
myutils/
    a/
        somestuff.py
    b/
        otherstuff.py
```

which is exactly what I want after installing them both with pip.

My problem is that uninstalling the second package (with pip) also wipes out the first one -- this is not what I want to happen.  I would like it just to remove myutils.b and keep myutils.a where it is.

I suspect I'm confusing things with having multiple **init**.py files in with myutils/ folders, but I'm not sure how else to get these to work properly.

--

Also found this helpful page:

http://www.sourceweaver.com/musings/posts/python-namespace-packages

Comment: The link is changed to http://www.sourceweaver.com/post/94805194515/python-namespace-packages

Answer (score 10):

If I'm understanding this correctly, what you are trying to set up is a namespace package (an empty package that contains other, separately installed packages), which is a [feature of setuptools](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#namespace-packages).

Call `setuptools.setup()` with a list of packages that are namespaces for the `namespace_packages` argument.

```
setup(..., namespace_packages=['myutils'], ...)
```

Then, create `myutils/__init__.py` containing only the following:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Finally, in `myutils/a/__init__.py` and `myutils/b/__init__.py` call `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('myutils')`, which ensures that the namespace is created if a lower-level package is installed first.

I'm pretty sure that's how it works. I'm still learning setuptools so if I'm wrong, corrections are much appreciated.

Comment: The link "feature of setuptools" is broken. It now is https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/